# Weird behavior on Gnome Desktop

Tags: debian, gnome

I'm using Debian Jessie and randomly my Desktop become like this:

[image]

As you can see, the programs work well (Spotify on the example), but the texts icons on bottom of screen and when Alt-Tab or disappear or missing some letters.

Comment: I believe this is a hardware-specific bug (well, surprise) on intel graphics. You should name your graphics hardware specifically! I expect it will clear up on logout+log back in again. By default intel hardware will use xserver-xorg-video-intel, but "The use of this driver is discouraged if your hw is new enough (ca. 2007 and newer). You can try uninstalling this driver and let the server use it's builtin modesetting driver instead."

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks for the tip. I've just removed the xserver-xorg-video-intel using apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel, and let's see if the problem vanishes.